# Rendering Rails Partial from AJAX and passing in local variables from AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to render a Rails partial with an AJAX request like in this link (and also pass in local variables to the rendered partial):

http://isotope11.com/blog/render-partials-with-ajax-requests

What he is doing is using .get to do an ajax call to a controller that renders a partial:

```
  $.get("/ean_hotels/"+ id, params, function(data){
  $('#hotelModalContent').html(data);
  }, "html");

  $('#hotelModal').reveal();
```

And the "render" at the end of his controller action in hotels_controller.rb:

```
render partial: 'hotel_modal_content', locals: { hotel: @hotel, hotel_review_widget: hotel_review_widget }, layout: false
```

you can see that the controller code sets local variables for the partial to be rendered (i.e. hotel and hotel_review_widget).

I don't understand how to pass in these local variables from the original .get AJAX call.

I'm also not sure what params is for when doing the AJAX call with .get

I'd like to be able to pass in local variables from javascript through to the hotels_controller.rb which maps a local variable to a variable in the partial.

I appreciate any help here.

EDIT:

Adding partial code

_hotel_model_content.html.erb

```
<h3><%= hotel %></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client**

According to the [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs, `params` will go into the query string part of the URL:

```
// request to /somethings?a=abc&b=2
$.get('/somethings', {a: 'abc', b: 2})
```

**Server**

Query string parameters can be accessed from Rails actions via a Hash-like object called `params`. [[1]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

```
class SomethingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts params[:a] # if URL was /somethings?a=123, will print 123
  end
end
```

**Putting it Together**

Let's make a complete example with a partial.

Here is the client code:

```
// client call to /somethings?name=Something+123
$.get('/somethings', {name: 'Something 123'}, function(data){
  $('#target').html(data);
});
```

Here is the server:

```
class SomethingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # bind controller variable @name
    @name = params[:name]
  end
end
```

Inside the view `app/views/somethings/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render :partial => 'some_partial', :locals => {:name => @name} %>
```

I've moved the partial rendering into a view. I think rendering partials from views is more standard than rendering partials directly from controllers.

Comment: thanks @sebastian goodman. This makes a lot of sense but for some reason, I can't get the local variable to pass through. Stil getting error of "a undefined local variable or method `name' for #<#<Class:0x007f92b4764258>:0x007f92b4761378>"  I tried a few other ways like render :partial => 'some_partial', :locals => { :name => @name} but not working either.  Wonder what gives.  I know the rest of it works though because if I just put @name into the partial, it passes through the params of name

Comment: I've refactored my answer a little bit, because there may be problems rendering partials directly from the controller. Try it this way and see if it works.

Comment: i just added the partial code. I agree with your latest comment that rendering partials directly from controller and trying to pass local variables through surfaces some issues.  I'll have to figure out to make what I'm doing work with rendering the partial from a view. It'll take some thinking because the reason why I wanted to render the partial from the controller is because the partial being rendered was dynamic from an ajax call. Thanks for the help! Will let you know.

Comment: I ended up just passing in the params from the AJAX call in as instance variables to the partial view that I was rendering.  so just straight used @hotel. i like your answer though because of the specific example that you provided. helped me completely understand what was happening